# Why set the sheet index for the sheet?

Tags: php, phpexcel

I want to know the meaning and use of the third statement in the below code. What is the meaning of it? What is the purpose of setting the index? What is the use of it? Can anyone provide the answer for this. The code snippet is:

```
$excel = new PHPExcel(); 
$excel->createSheet(); 
$excel->setActiveSheetIndex(1);
```

Comment: a quick search on google with setActiveSheetIndex(1) can provide you withe the correct answer. There are plenty of resources there: some are also questions here on SO. Have you tried to search at least here before posting?

Answer (score 1):

Well, looking at a bigger picture, let me try to explain...

The setActiveSheetIndex (as per documentation) is used to set the ActiveSheetIndex.

When creating one sheet, it might seem insignificant, but when you have multiple sheets in picture with lots of data, then it becomes easy to switch between sheets and write data into them. It is then that this line of code becomes highly significant.

Hope that helps!